# Subversion: Review changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm used to [VSSConneXion](http://www.epocalipse.com/vcx.htm), and love the feature 'Review Changes' where I can go through every changed file and comment the change while looking at it:

[image]

Now I'm trying to get used to SubVersion and Tortoise. Is there a similar feature available? I can get a list of changed file, and I can diff each file for changes, but I can't find a way to comment on the changes while looking at the diffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically simply use the TortoiseSVN commit dialog for this.

- svn commit => dialog shows up with list of changes
- one by one, I can review the changes, and write my commit message in the dialog
- the best part of it is that TortoiseSVN remembers commit messages. Even if I click cancel, I can continue with the same message previously created.

Very simple, no extra tools needed.

Comment: So by putting the diff-window and the commit dialog side by side, I can review and write at the same time. Good. I assumed the diff-window was modal, and didn't check...
My previous message, that was canceled, is saved 'behind' the recent messages-button.
I think this solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking for generic code review, there are *lots* of tools that work with `svn`. One of the most prominent is [ReviewBoard](http://www.review-board.org/).

If you're asking about a way to add commit log messages, then there's a bit of a conceptual mismatch: `svn` uses atomic commits, so all the changes in a given commit get the same message.

Comment: I talk about commit log messages. I understand that commits are atomic, whereas checkins in VSS is not, but even though the message is given to every file I commit, I like to summarize the changes that I have done. So what I want, is a place to write where I see the changes done.